# How to check if my ISP blocks port 25?

Tags: smtp

How should I check if my ISP blocks port 25?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
cmd> telnet <some well known email provider IP> 25
```

to determine which exactly host (subdomain) is listening port 25:

```
nslookup -q=MX <top-level domain>
```

For example:

```
cmd> nslookup -q=MX gmail.com

gmail.com       MX preference = 50, mail exchanger = gsmtp147.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 50, mail exchanger = gsmtp183.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com

gsmtp147.google.com     internet address = 209.85.147.27
gsmtp183.google.com     internet address = 64.233.183.27
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com      internet address = 64.233.183.114

cmd> telnet gsmtp147.google.com 25

220 mx.google.com ESMTP l27si12759488waf.25
```

On Linux, you can 'dig', I guess.

Comment: linux alternative to finding domain to telnet:    $ dig mx gmail.com

Answer (score 6):

http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: Correct answer if the questioner meant "blocked inbound". Although failure doesn't *necessarily* mean your ISP is blocking it, it could be your own firewall.

Answer (score 4):

telnet host 25

Just select a host that you know is listening on port 25.

Comment: Correct answer if the questioner meant "blocked outbound".

Answer (score 2):

You could call them and ask.

Comment: Dunno.  My ISP is a paid service provider, and should be truthful about it, don't you think?

Comment: They may have to be honest, but they aren't legally required to be well-informed.

Answer (score 2):

Probing a server that listens on your desired port is of course the best option, as abatishchev has shown.

In the case where you can't find an "echo" service on your desired port or *you want to know who is blocking you* on the path you can resort to *firewalking*. Firewalking probes the path by starting with a Time-To-Live (TTL) set to zero and then icrementing it by one each iteration. When you stop getting "ICMP TTL Exceeded" messages that means the next hop in the chain is filtering your packets.

You can use [hping3](http://www.hping.org/) to do this:

```
:~$ hping3 -z -T -p 25 server.com
```

or use [Firewalk](http://www.packetfactory.net/projects/firewalk/) which was created for exactly this.

**Edit**: Any NAT devices on the route will silently destroy your results since the TTL is reset to whatever sane value the router sees fit.