# Can't connect to port 25 on Google Compute instance (incoming SMTP)

Tags: smtp, firewall, google-compute-engine

I am running postfix on a Google Compute instance. It is listening on 0.0.0.0:25, and I have opened port 25 on the firewall, but I cannot connect to it from the outside. I have reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692366/telnet-to-google-mail-server) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819545/google-compute-engine-will-not-allow-incoming-smtp-connections), but they do not resolve my issue. I don't see anything in the Google Compute documentation that would explain this.

The port is open on the firewall:

```
% gcutil --project=XXX getfirewall smtp
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| name          | smtp                          |
| description   | Incoming smtp allowed.        |
| creation-time | 2014-06-08T13:29:16.052-07:00 |
| network       | default                       |
| source-ips    | 0.0.0.0/0                     |
| source-tags   |                               |
| target-tags   |                               |
| allowed       | tcp: 25                       |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

From the outside, I can connect to port 80 (which is also open)...

```
% telnet 108.XXX.XXX.XXX 80
Trying 108.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Connected to 108.XXX.XXX.XXX.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ...>
...
</html>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

...but not to port 25:

```
% telnet 108.XXX.XXX.XXX 25
Trying 108.XXX.XXX.XXX...
telnet: connect to address 108.XXX.XXX.XXX: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

postfix is listening on all interfaces:

```
% gcutil --project=XXX ssh --zone=us-central1-a XXX sudo netstat -lpn -A inet
...
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10794/master
...
```

I can look up the "external" address...

```
% gcutil --project=XXX ssh --zone=us-central1-a XXX /sbin/ifconfig eth0
...
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0a:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:10.XXX.XXX.XXX  Bcast:10.XXX.XXX.XXX  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:46397953 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2
          TX packets:34953374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5031906871 (4.6 GiB)  TX bytes:49375287245 (45.9 GiB)
```

...and telnet to port 25 on it from the box:

```
% gcutil --project=XXX ssh --zone=us-central1-a XXX telnet 10.XXX.XXX.XXX 25
...
Trying 10.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Connected to 10.XXX.XXX.XXX.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 XXX ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
EHLO localhost
250-XXX
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many ISPs limit your ability to make an *outgoing* connection on port 25 (to help prevent spam from botnets). Have you verified that you can connect to a different known good SMTP server?

Comment: I agree with Greg that this is you most likely issue. To get around this issue we open both ports 25 and 26 in postfix, and get users to change to 26 if they have problems. (we only have a very small amount of users.)

Comment: You very well might be right. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328914/how-to-check-if-my-isp-blocks-port-25), and am unable to connect to the gmail.com MX hosts.

Comment: Greg, I am now convinced you and complistic are correct. If you want to write up an answer, I can select it as responsive to my question. Otherwise, I can answer it myself, but I wanted to provide you with the opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GregHewgill and @complistic pointed out in their respective comments, it is my ISP (or an intermediary) who was not routing traffic for port 25. I have been unable to connect to any port 25 outside of my immediate LAN. It is somewhat embarrassing that I have never noticed this before.

Hopefully anyone with a similar issue can find this question (and answer) before spinning their wheels in ignorance like I did.

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: I’ve been struggling with the same issue for hours. I’ve read your answer twice not realizing my ISP was blocking my tests. Only by the end of the day I realized what was going on. Feeling pretty embarrassed too 

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link [Blocked traffic](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#blockedtraffic) where it says that Google blocks or restricts traffic through all of the following ports/protocols between the Internet and virtual machines on specified ports.

Hope this helps.

Mary

Comment: Mary, thanks for the response. The link you provide describes what traffic Google blocks _from_ Google Compute instances. My question had to do with traffic going _to_ those instances. I was already familiar with that link, but thank you for the pointer.